# How to use "group by" to group data by the IP

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip-address, aggregation

How to use `group by` to group data by the IP range in postgres?

**My table:**

```
   "NETADDR"    |
----------------|
 192.168.13.6   |   
 192.168.13.6   |
 192.168.14.5   |
 192.168.14.6   |
```

**Desired output:**

```
   "NETADDR"    |    "COUNT"
----------------|----------------|
 192.168.13     |      2
 192.168.14     |      2
```

Comment: What type is `netaddr`?

Comment: Type Is varchar

Comment: Consider using [`cidr`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-CIDR). It will make this easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if `cidr` would make this that much more efficient, because you still need to aggregate.  You can construct the Type C address using array functions:

```
select array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(netaddr, '\.'))[1:3], '.') as typec,
       count(*)
from t
group by typec;
```

Or using regular expressions:

```
select regexp_replace(netaddr, '(^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.]+[0-9]).*$', '\1') as typec,
       count(*)
from t
group by typec
```

Answer (score 1):

[Gordon covered doing this as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61600678/14660). Storing and processing IP addresses as strings makes this and other processes slow and difficult and obtuse.

Instead, store them as [`cidr`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-CIDR) and use [`set_masklen`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html) to group addresses by their /24.

```
select
  set_masklen(netaddr, 24) as subnet,
  count(*)
from mytable
group by subnet
```

Though it may not benefit this particular query, `cidr` can be indexed using [gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist.html) with [inet_ops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html) to benefit other queries.

```
create index on mytable using gist(netaddr inet_ops);
```

If you can't change the column type, you can still make use of the cidr functions with casting. `set_masklen(netaddr::cidr, 24)`

Answer (score 0):

How to get the first two octets in an IP address Oracle SQL?

Regex solution : SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("youField", '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.') AS "output"

Reference URL: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173277/how-to-get-the-first-two-octets-in-an-ip-address-oracle-sql

How to get the first three octets in an IP address Oracle SQL?
It's working for me.

select REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_IP_FIELD, '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+') as IP_Block, count(*) as Number_Of_IP
from YOUR_TABLE group by REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_IP_FIELD, '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+')